# What's the proper way to set up date fields for a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, date, scaffold, rails-generate

So I have 3 fields in my HTML, lunchMonth, lunchDay and lunchYear

lunchMonth and lunchDay are Select tags with option tags for months and days remaining in the year. lunchYear is set to 2011.

I've set up a form but I need to generate a scaffold to take these 3 values.

What's the proper way to do this?

> Rails generate scaffold Date month:string date:integer year:integer

Is that right?

Comment: Are you saving month as 'Jan, Fed'?

Comment: november, december, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use select tags or write out your HTML with `scaffold` rails will do that for you. do `rails generate scaffold LunchTimes lunch_on:date` (NOTE: rails has a `date` data type.)

and rails will generate views in `app/views/lunch_times/*` that use the `select_date` helper to generate the needed HTML.

it will also generate a model in `app/models/lunch_time.rb` and a controller: `app/controllers/lunch_times_constrollers.rb`

EDIT:

I'd encourage you to checkout the Rails Guides here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html

http://api.rubyonrails.org is also a good reference.

I've found them very helpful.

Comment: I generated that. What would the next step be? I guess I should delete all of this HTML with Select Tags and Option Tags?

Comment: try viewing what you have with `rails s` or `rails server` and point your browser to http://localhost:3000, see if this is what you want.